# import two versions of library in same Python script?

Tags: python, keras, import

I want to do:

```
from keras import applications              # keras==2.2.4
from keras.layers import TextVectorization  # keras==2.6.0
```

Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that. Besides keras probably imports its own stuff too and different modules/classes imported from different versions will be incompatible. There is a reason versions exist. Why do you need that?

Comment: I am trying to use a third library that uses something from keras==2.2.4, but in the same script I am using something from keras==2.6.0. What should be the best practice in this situation?

Comment: There is no easy solution. Is your third party library absolutely not able to work with 2.6.0 or is it just a `setup.py` dependency issue? You may try forking keras 2.2.4 on github and cherry pick the features you want from 2.6.0, ending up with your own hybrid version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two version of same libraries in the same environment is not possible. it will automatically uninstall the existing version while installing the other